# Invalid initializer member declarator asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help me. I can't convert Id from IdentityUser.Convert.ToInt32(Id) : error invalid initializer member declarator.

```
private static void SetUser(User user, IdentityUser identityUser)
{
    user.Password = identityUser.PasswordHash;
    user.SecurityStamp = identityUser.SecurityStamp;

    user.UserId = Convert.ToInt32( identityUser.Id);
    user.UserName = identityUser.UserName;
    user.UserEmailAddress = identityUser.Email;
}
private IdentityUser ToIdentityUser(User user)
{
    // IdentityUser identityUser = new IdentityUser();
    return new IdentityUser
           {
               Convert.ToInt32(Id) = user.UserId,
               PasswordHash = user.Password,
               SecurityStamp = user.SecurityStamp,
               UserName = user.UserName,
               Email = user.UserEmailAddress
           };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually have two `Convert.ToInt32(Id)` statements, but I'm assuming the problematic one is in the `ToIdentityUser()` method.

Note that an *lvalue* cannot be a call to a method.  In other words, the statement:

```
Convert.ToInt32(Id) = user.UserId,
```

cannot be correct.  Perhaps you intended:

```
Id = Convert.ToInt32(user.UserId),
```

Comment: Thanks for anwser , but I want convert Id to Int because Id is string type and UserId (in my database) is int type.  Id = Convert.ToInt32(user.UserId) : error cannot implicity convert type 'int' to 'string'